# OnActivityResult Called Before Phone Connected On A CALL Intent

Tags: java, kotlin

Why is my onActivityresult called just before the intent is started and not after the call is done and user is back to the app. I watch my logs and message "A call has ended" happens right before the call is made.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == CALL_REQUEST_CODE) {
        Log.d("----------", "A call has ended")
    }
}

 binding.call.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "0793013887"))
        startActivityForResult(intent, CALL_REQUEST_CODE)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The onActivityResult method is typically called after the activity that was started with startActivityForResult returns and finishes its work, and sends back the result to the original activity. However, in the case of making a phone call, the startActivityForResult method may not behave as expected.

When you call startActivityForResult with an intent to make a phone call, the system does not start a new activity to make the call, instead it sends an intent to the Phone app, which starts the call. Since your app is not actually waiting for a result from the Phone app, onActivityResult is called immediately after the startActivityForResult method, before the phone call is made.

As a result logs show "A call has ended" message right before the call is made because the onActivityResult method is called immediately after the startActivityForResult method, and not after the call is made and the user is back to the app.